# WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2397' ('MQRC_JSSE_ERROR'

Tags: java, queue, jms, websphere, ibm-mq

I'm trying to connect to a WMQ from a JMS client, but the connectivity is failing. I've added the certificates and JCE extensions.
The linked exceptions are

```
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002 JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with 
compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2397' ('MQRC_JSSE_ERROR'). 
[com.ibm.mq.MQException] at:
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:413)
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8475)
---
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002 Object ClassLoader = org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@77459877
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002 CurrentThread ClassLoader = org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@77459877
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002  Cause:
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002 CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'abc.com(1419)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=java.net.SocketException[Connection reset],3=abc.com/111.111.111.111:1419 (abc.com),4=SSLSocket.startHandshake,5=default]],3=abc.com(1419),5=RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect] [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException] at:
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:2282)
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1294)
---
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002   com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:376)
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002 CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=java.net.SocketException[Connection reset],3=abc.com/111.111.111.111:1419 (abc.com),4=SSLSocket.startHandshake,5=default] [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException] at:
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1325)
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
----
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002 Object ClassLoader = org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@77459877
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002 CurrentThread ClassLoader = org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@77459877
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002  Cause:
[26/04/18 16:52:05.797.1G]  0002 Connection reset [java.net.SocketException] at:
```

Comment: What is the version in the MANIFEST.MF in the com.ibm.mq jar files you reference?

Comment: Is that relevant, Does it have any relation with anything Specification-Version: 2.0 Implementation-Version: 8.0.0.4

Comment: It is relevant.  Version should be 4 parts. Ex 8.0.0.1 the last number is relevant

Comment: Actually the issue is occurring when we move the application to AWS, it was working previously. I'm not aware we need to do any other specific modifications related to this connection.

Comment: Is the any reason not to divulge the full 4 digit version?

Comment: @JoshMc 8.0.0.4, I've mentioned above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171963/discussion-between-jones-j-alapat-and-joshmc).